# In R, does "glmnet" fit an intercept?

Tags: r, regression, lasso

I am fitting a linear model in R using `glmnet`. The original (non-regularized) model was fitted using `lm` and did not have a constant term (i.e. it was in the form `lm(y~0+x1+x2,data)`).

`glmnet` takes a matrix of predictors and a vector of responses. I've been reading `glmnet` documentation, and can find no mention of the constant term.

So, is there a way to ask `glmnet` to force the linear fit through the origin?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, an intercept is included in a [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) model, but it is not regularized (cf. [Regularization Paths for Generalized Linear Models via Coordinate Descent](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/glmnet.pdf), p. 13). More details about the implementation could certainly be obtained by carefully looking at the code (for a gaussian family, it is the `elnet()` function that is called by `glmnet()`), but it is in Fortran.

You could try the [penalized](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/index.html) package, which allows to remove the intercept by passing `unpenalized = ~0` to `penalized()`.

```
> x <- matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
> y <- rnorm(100)
> fit1 <- penalized(y, penalized=x, unpenalized=~0, 
                    standardize=TRUE) 
> fit2 <- lm(y ~ 0+x)
> plot((coef(fit1) + coef(fit2))/2, coef(fit2)-coef(fit1))
```

To get Lasso regularization, you might try something like

```
> fit1b <- penalized(y, penalized=x, unpenalized=~0, 
                     standardize=TRUE, lambda1=1, steps=20)
> show(fit1b)
> plotpath(fit1b)
```

As can be seen in the next figure, there is little differences between the regression parameters computed with both methods (left), and you can plot the Lasso path solution very easily (right).

[image]