# Binomial regression with penalized ML

Tags: r, glmnet

These coefficients look way too large to me, they seem to imply probabilities of around 0.5, instead of around .01, as I would expect.

Here is sample code:

```
set.seed(1L)
ids <- as.factor(rep(1:10,rep(10,10)))
ps <- rnorm(n=10,mean=0.01,sd=.002)
ns <- sample(500:2000,replace=T,size=100)
ks <- rbinom(n=100,size=ns,prob=ps)
X <- model.matrix(~ 0 + ids)
mod.simple <- glmnet(x=X,y=cbind(ks,ns-ks),alpha=1,standardize=F,
                     family="binomial")
mod.simple$beta
```

This gives betas ranging in absolute value from 0 to .16, depending on the penalty parameter lambda.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Why do you think these beta values are not acceptable?

Comment: my understanding is that since the probabilities are so low (and there is no intercept, the betas will also be small, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the answer is that glmnet automatically fits an intercept term.  So my betas as reported by glmnet are actually the "true" betas + intercept.  This is rather unfortunate, because my model is conceptually clearer without an intercept term.

Comment: About your last point, you can try another package, e.g. [penalized](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/index.html) (see here more details, [In R, does “glmnet” fit an intercept?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4543/in-r-does-glmnet-fit-an-intercept)).

Comment: Thank you for the reference (it looks like an interesting package), but in my real problem I am actually using sparse Matrices, which it appears penalized does not support.