# How to use glmnet without the intercept?

Tags: r, lasso, glmnet

I know the `glmnet()` function *cannot* exclude the intercept by users, but does anyone know how to derive the fit without intercept from the `glmnet()`?

Comment: It's not obvious to me that this would be possible. The model could be completely different without an intercept, and I'm not sure why there should be an easy path from one model to the other.  Can you explain why you think this is feasible?  Perhaps you could use another method instead?  For instance, `bayesglm` in the `arm` package can fit regularized glms without intercepts (although they aren't sparse).  Might be worth looking into other options as well, rather than forcing glmnet to do something it doesn't want to.

Comment: You can also try the [penalized](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/index.html) package, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4554/930.

Comment: I wonder how to overcome this difficulty since glmnet() takes less computation time than other function (e.g. lars(), penalized(), lassoshooting()) for  solving the LASSO problem and the linear model I consider has to be through the origin.

Answer (score 20):

For compleness' sake (and because I accidentally bumped in to this question): starting with [version 1.9-3](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/ChangeLog), fitting without intercepts is supported (intercept=FALSE).