# Using deviation coding (effect coding) of factors in glmnet LASSO in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, lasso, glmnet, categorical-encoding

Various sources have instructed me how to use deviation coding (aka effects coding) in R (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52132/how-to-do-regression-with-effect-coding-instead-of-dummy-coding-in-r), [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94010/understanding-dummy-manual-or-automated-variable-creation-in-glm])).

My question though, is how to go about doing this for LASSO regression using glmnet?

To properly create a matrix to feed glmnet for LASSO regression, I use `model.matrix()` (as recommended by [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/210075/80624), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72251/an-example-lasso-regression-using-glmnet-for-binary-outcome), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156098/cross-validating-lasso-regression-in-r), etc.).

According to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/156301/80624) CV answer (and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/107958/80624) one), however, you should remove the intercept from the resulting matrix before feeding the matrix into a `glmnet` function because `glmnet` auto generates its own intercept.

1. What does this mean? (How is the intercept defined in glmnet? -- see below for concern)

In my case, I have a 62-level factor as an independent variable. However, none of the levels serve as a reference level. So I wanted to use deviation coding (ala `contrasts = 'contr.sum'` in `model.matrix`) so that no factor is used as a reference. (this is opposed to the standard 'treatment' contrasts used in R).

2. **My main question**: will glmnet create an intercept that would otherwise be identical to the one I created using contr.sum (deviation coding) in creating my matrix?

   - My concern is that my dummy variables will all be based on grand means in a deviation coding system, but my regression will use an intercept that thinks that all my factor dummy variables are relative to a reference level.
   - Do I need to suppress the intercept in glmnet?
   - Do I need to introduce a contrasts argument into glmnet?
3. Follow-up question: When creating my model matrix using deviation coding, do I need to modify my equation?

   - Ex. Currently I have `y ~ factor(x) + z`. Do I need to modify this equation any when using deviation coding vs. strict treatment dummy coding? (e.g., `y ~ -1 + factor(x) + z`)?

---

Context: I'm creating a *predictive* model and am less concerned about interpretability (though, the model of course still needs to be valid!).

Comment: `I have a 62-level factor as an independent variable. However, none of the levels serve as a reference level. So I wanted to use deviation coding`. Contrast of any type needs a reference category, deviation type too. In this [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/221868/3277) (showing how one can prepare contrasts to use in a regression program when he doesn't have specialized ANOVA program) I considered various contrast types, all of them needs a reference group.

Comment: note: you can suppress the intercept in glmnet, according to this CV [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/58433/80624) and confirmed by me. Just set argument `intercept = FALSE`.