# Does R glmnet regularize on intercept?

Tags: r, regularization, linear, glmnet, intercept

Both [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4543/in-r-does-glmnet-fit-an-intercept) and original paper, suggest `R` `glmnet` does not regularize the intercept.

But why I am observing the intercept shrink to $0$ in following experiment?

```
library(glmnet)
n=1e4
p=1e2
x=matrix(runif(n*p),nrow=n)-100
y=sample(0:1,n,replace = T)
fit=glmnet(x,y, alpha=0, family="binomial")
plot(fit$lambda,fit$a0)
```

### [image]

Thanks for @seanv507's answer, the experiment has a problem of "true intercept" is $\log(0.5/0.5)=0$. Here is a revised version, where we set `y=sample(0:1,n,replace = T, prob=c(0.9,0.1))`, and the intercept is converging to true value $\log(0.1/0.9)=-0.2197$.

[image]

Comment: At least officially it is not. "*the intercept is not regularized*" as mentioned in [Regularization Paths for Generalized Linear Models
via Coordinate Descent](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v33/i01/paper).

Comment: Ordinarily, it is (strongly) advisable to standardize the columns of the model matrix when regularizing.  Incidentally, I believe (although I haven't actually tried it) that you *can* regularize the intercept: include a constant term in the model matrix and specify to `glmnet` that you do not want it to include an intercept term automatically. Doing so might help you see the difference between regularizing the intercept and not.

Comment: @whuber, glmnet defaults to standardising  the columns. (also it does it internally to the algorithm so the sparsity of the matrix is preserved - which is important for "big data" problems)

Comment: @hxd1011.Sorry, maybe I misunderstand the experiment. The y is independent of X, namely p(y=1)=0.5. So the true model is intercept =0 and all the other coefficients likewise 0. So regularisation is converging to true model, not biasing to wrong model. So I believe your interpretation is mistaken ; regularisation is preventing the random variation in the x and y to have an effect so that the true (parsimonious)  model is recovered.

Comment: @sean Thank you for clarifying the behavior of `glmnet` with respect to standardization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not penalize the intercept. But it does penalize the covariates, which are correlated with the intercept. Thus, changing the estimates of the coefficients for the non-constant variables changes the estimates of the intercept.

To help see that, note that in your dataset, all your covariates are in the interval $[-100, -99]$, making the estimate of the intercept highly correlated with the estimate of covariates; if you resimulate your data several times, you will note that for small $\lambda$, the estimated intercept is all over the place. If you remove the `-100` from the creation of the covariates, the estimate of intercept is much closer to 0 for small values of $\lambda$, as the covariates are less likely to "drag" the intercept.

Comment: thanks! I also revised the question that make "true intercept" not equal to $0$, but you helped on how why the intercept changes!